# How do I test if a submit button exists in capybara?

Tags: ruby, rspec, capybara

I want to have a test in rspec for the existence of a submit button. I am using capybara as well.

I have tried:

```
should have_tag("input","Submit button")
```

and

```
should have_content("Submit, button")
```

but it either raises an exception or gives false positives.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

These are all good suggestions, but if you want to confirm that it's a button and that it has the right value (for display), you have to be a little more detailed:

```
page.should have_selector("input[type=submit][value='Press Me']")
```

I don't know of an existing matcher that does this.  Here's a custom RSpec2 matcher I wrote:

```
RSpec::Matchers.define :have_submit_button do |value|
  match do |actual|
    actual.should have_selector("input[type=submit][value='#{value}']")
  end
end
```

Here's the RSpec3 version (courtesy @zwippie):

```
RSpec::Matchers.define :have_submit_button do |value|
  match do |actual|
    expect(actual).to have_selector("input[type=submit][value='#{value}']")
  end
end
```

I keep it in `spec/support/matchers/request_matchers.rb` with my other custom matchers.  RSpec picks it up automatically.  Since this is an RSpec matcher (rather than a Capybara finder), it will work in both feature specs (Capybara) and view specs (RSpec without Capybara).

Feature spec usage:

```
page.should have_submit_button("Save Me")
```

View spec usage (after calling `render`):

```
rendered.should have_submit_button("Save Me")
```

Note that if you're in a Capybara request spec, and you would like to interact with a submit button, that's a lot easier:

```
click_button "Save Me"
```

There's no guarantee that it's actually a submit button, but your feature specs should just be testing the behavior and not worrying about that level of detail.

Comment: For RSpec 3, replace the third line with: `expect(actual).to have_selector("input[type=submit][value='#{value}']")`.

Comment: Thanks! Updated the answer to include that as well.

Answer (score 17):

There is a built-in matcher [has_button?](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/Capybara/Node/Matchers#has_button%3F-instance_method).

Using RSpec you can have an assertion like

```
page.should have_button('Submit button')
```

Or with new RSpec 3 syntax:

```
expect(page).to have_button('Submit button')
```

Answer (score 2):

I have one (used in cucumber):

```
Then /^I should see "([^"]*)" button/ do |name|
  should have_button name
end
```

In negative use: have_no_button

Answer (score 1):

if your HTML mark up is just something like:

```
<input type="submit"></input>
```

Then you can do the following in capybara:

```
page.should have_selector('input[type=submit]')
```

Answer (score 0):

I have something like:

```
page.find("#submitButton").visible?
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

```
it { should have_xpath("//input[@value='Sign up']") }
```

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
it { should have_selector('input', value: "Submit") }
```

UPDATE: I suspect this answer may not work as desired in some cases. When I use this to test for the value in other input tags, it seems to pass no matter what the value is.

Comment: This didn't work for me. I ended up using Jim Stewart's answer

Comment: I tried this as well, didn't work. Jim Stewart's answer did work.

Comment: `value` is not a valid key. should be one of `:text, :visible, :between, :count, :maximum, :minimum, :exact, :match, :wait`